# Sweet alert dialog with spinner in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, sweetalert

I am trying to display a spinner in a `sweet alert` dialog something close to Bootstrap modal dialog (http://jsfiddle.net/D6rD6/5/)

The closest i could come up with is something like this :

```
SweetAlert.swal({
title: '<small>Import errors occurred !</small>',
text: '<i class="fa fa-spinner" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
html: true,
customClass: 'manual-upload-errors-swal-width'
});
```

If this is not possible whats the closest and best solution ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The original sweet alert plugin is unsupported, I suggest you using [SweetAlert2](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2) plugin.

Migration is simple, here's the migration guide: [Migration from SweetAlert to SweetAlert2](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/wiki/Migration-from-SweetAlert-to-SweetAlert2)

In SweetAlert2 there's `swal.showLoading()`, so you can show loading modal as easy as:

```js
Swal.fire('Please wait')
Swal.showLoading()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```

Comment: Is there a way i can use different spinner ?

Comment: No, currently there's only this spinner implemented. To use other spinners you should hide buttons (`showConfirmButton: false`) and pass a custom spinner to the `html` paremeter.

Comment: How do you stop it?

Comment: @OsamaKhalid you have Swal.close()

Answer (score 1):

This code works fine for showing Loading Spinner.

```js
    const showLoading = function() {
        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Please Wait',
            allowEscapeKey: false,
            allowOutsideClick: false,
            background: '#19191a',
            showConfirmButton: false,
            onOpen: ()=>{
                Swal.showLoading();
            }

            // timer: 3000,
            // timerProgressBar: true
        });
    };
    
    showLoading();
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- scale=1.0"/>

    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@sweetalert2/theme-dark@3" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

</html>
```